# Laravel Request object host set to ELB hostname instead of current hostname

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.5, aws-elb

I have a Laravel app deployed to AWS, which is load balanced via an ELB across 2 app servers.

The issue I'm having is that in the Laravel request, the `host` property is set to the ELB's hostname, instead of the current hostname.

This means that things like the `route()` helper are generating URLs with the ELB hostname rather than the correct hostname.

For example, I expect:

```
https://www-testing.testapp.com/my-route
```

But I get:

```
https://elb-testing.testapp.com/my-route
```

This seems like strange behaviour, and I'm unsure how to resolve the issue in a sensible way.